# Stack around variable corrupted. Why does this happen?

Tags: c++, mfc, buffer

I defined `BufferOut` as a 16 element array.

But I face this message while debugging.

`Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'BufferOut' was corrupted.`

`HIDBufferOut` is an 16 element of `char` array

```
 HIDBufferOut BufferOut; // first element is the report ID 
    BufferOut[0] = 0; 
    BufferOut[1] = 211; 
    BufferOut[16] = 44; 
    BufferOut[4] = 4;

    .
    .
    .
    .
    etc
```

Comment: The error message is descriptive enough. If you cannot figure it out, then neither can we without seeing the source code.

Comment: `HIDBufferOut BufferOut;
  
  // first element is the report ID
  BufferOut[0] = 0;


  BufferOut[1]  = Marker();
  BufferOut[16] = (int) 44;
  BufferOut[4]  = typ;
`

Comment: since you are inserting 17th element in the array

Comment: BufferOut is a 16-element array of what?  What does Marker() actually do?  What is typ?  You need to post a minimal example of your code that causes the issue and also give some sort of explanation of what the variables are.

Comment: @user1091216 I see you have "updated" your code. However, I still see no array. Where is your array of 16 elements? I see a single HIDBufferOut named BufferOut.....

Answer (score 2):

If `BufferOut` is a 16 element buffer, then valid indices are 0, ..., 15. This means that:

```
BufferOut[16] = (int) 44;
```

writes out of bounds of the array, causing memory corruption.

Comment: i tried to define it with 17 elements and the problem still the same

Comment: Where do you create your array? I don't see it in your code above.

Comment: @user1091216: if so, then you still gave not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

this usually occurs when you write on the location that's beyond your reach causing buffer overflow, and stack corruption as clear from this piece of your code:
BufferOut[16] = (int) 44; //you are writing out of bounds on 17th location

Comment: change the array size to 17 elements, if it still persists, Do clean and than fresh build the project from scratch helps at times.

Answer (score -1):

may this help you

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/7454

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/37292/

Comment: You might want to read [this relevant Meta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) regarding link-only answers.